# MySQL - Selecting Duplicates across 3 columns and joining with another table to filter

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a Purchases table, where I'm trying to select all rows where first name, surname and email are duplicates (for all 3).

Purchases table:

```
| purchase_id   | product_id | user_id       | firstname   | surname   | email       |   
| ------------- | -----------| ------------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 1             | 1          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | s@gmail.com |
| 2             | 2          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | s@gmail.com |
| 3             | 3          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | s@gmail.com |
| 4             | 1          | 888           | Bob         | Smith     | b@gmail.com |
```

Further to this, each product ID corresponds to a product type in a 'Products' table, and I'm trying to filter by 'lawnmower' purchases (so only product ID 1 & 2)

Products table:

```
| product_type  | product_id |
| ------------- | -----------| 
| lawnmower     | 1          | 
| lawnmower     | 2          | 
| leafblower    | 3          |
```

I'm hoping to write a query that will return all purchases of the 'lawnmower' type where first name, last name, and email are duplicates (so would return the first two rows of the Purchases table).

This is where my query is at so far, however it's not returning accurate data (e.g. I know I have around 350 duplicates and it's returning 10,000 rows):

```
SELECT t. * 
FROM database_name.purchases t
JOIN (
    SELECT firstname, surname, email, count( * ) AS NumDuplicates
    FROM database_name.purchases
    GROUP BY firstname, surname, email
    HAVING NumDuplicates >1
)tsum ON t.firstname = tsum.firstname
AND t.surname = tsum.surname
AND t.email = tsum.email
INNER JOIN database_name.products p2 ON t.product_id = p2.product_id
WHERE p2.product_type = 'lawnmower'
```

Just wanting to know what I need to tweak in my query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You know that you should be returning Sally Smith. Create a table from the results of your query above. Then Select * from that table where first_name=sally and surname=Smith.   See if you can figure out where you are going wrong based on that. This will help you debug these type of issues yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `SELECT` does not filter on the product type. It gets all customers who have purchased any two items. Then you join it to `purchases` and therefore also get the purchases of customers who have bought any two items and, possibly only one, lawnmower. Add a filter on the product type in the subquery too:

```
SELECT t.* 
       FROM database_name.purchases t
            INNER JOIN (SELECT purchases.userid
                               FROM database_name.purchases
                                    INNER JOIN database_name.products
                                               ON products.product_id = purchases.product_id
                               WHERE products.product_type = 'lawnmower'
                               GROUP BY userid
                               HAVING count(*) > 1) s
                       ON t.user_id = s.user_id
            INNER JOIN database_name.products p
                       ON t.product_id = p.product_id
       WHERE p.product_type = 'lawnmower';
```

Your schema also is problematic -- denormalised. `firstname`, `surname` and `email` depend on `user_id` (Note that I only grouped and joined using the `user_id`, that's enough,). So they shouldn't be in `purchases`, only `user_id`. `product_type` better by an ID referencing to some product type table too.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for this. 

Just to clarify on the schema, first_name, surname and email don't depend on user_id - someone might have signed up twice and have 2 user_ids with same first_name, surname etc, and conversely I think there are a few cases in the database where the first name is slightly different within one user_id.

Comment: So I'm still needing a slightly modified version of this (checking for duplicates for across all of the firstname, surname and email fields, rather than user_id)